# Powershell and cmd: "normal" select text mode

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I find it quite infuriating how hard is to actually copy text in text only environments: Powershell and cmd. How can I simply select *rows* of text, not *blocks* of text? How did they came up up and think that block of text is more of a default option for selecting text?

Ending the rant, is a there a way to have a simple "select text, copy text" in Powershell or cmd?

For example, if I want to select MY TEXT here:

```
asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd MY
TEXT asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd a
```

and I block-select the two rows, I get 'asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd MY\nTEXT asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd a' (also, note the annoying \r\n) instead of the simple 'MY TEXT'

Comment: you say not selecting a block but how about selecting a block by clicking at the far left, pushing the mouse to the far right and dragging down, then you are selecting rows.

Comment: nope, i'm selecting far more than I want if, for example. see edit

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but the reasoning behind block select, I assume, is because many traditional DOS/CLI apps have ASCII-based [TUIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface) (e.g. [Norton Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander)) that would be impossible to select text from using non-block selection. However, this is a pretty rare use-case these days, so they should still have at least added the option for normal text selection.

Comment: mintty does but afaik mintty is only for cygwin

Comment: in Windows 10 line selection is the default

Comment: Who thought block select was a good idea?!

Answer (score 19):

You need to use modifier key while selecting to activate the feature.

Hold `ALT` and `Left Mouse Button` while dragging your mouse over the text to be selected.

Comment: You can make line-select as the default.

 1. Go to Power Shell Properties (right-click on the window title and select "Properties")
 2. In the first tab, check the box "Enable line wrapping selection".
 3. Hold `ALT` while dragging your mouse over the text to be selected.

Source: Anonymous

Comment: The above does not work in Windows 7, where the PowerShell behaves exactly as cmd.exe.

Comment: @RCross So is the 'normal' selection mode enabled by the default? Does windows 7 require a separate solution?

Comment: Yes; although I'm not aware of any native solution.

Comment: Ok - there is a workable solution, which is to use the PowerShell ISE instead of the PowerShell terminal.  It's been a while since I've used Windows 7 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Theres no direct way in window's console window to do this, but you can get exactly the behavior you want from console2, it also has a lot of other features that the default console window SHOULD have but doesn't. Note that this is not a replacement for cmd.exe, but rather, a replacement for the console window in which cmd.exe runs. You can use any console app as the shell (like powershell, etc). [Here's the link to it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console)

Comment: This also looks nice: http://mridgers.github.io/clink/

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, rather than using Powershell.exe, use Powershell ISE which has line-selection enabled by default.

If you particularly want block-select, hold ALT and use the Left Mouse Button to revert to the cmd.exe-style behaviour.